# Confidence Intervals for β1 and β2

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I'm having a bit of trouble with the question below.

Using this Data -> [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxOEl.png)

Question:
Establish $95\%$ confidence intervals for $β_2$ and $β_3$.

I know I use the formula:
$β_2 ±$ (t-value)(standard error)

How do I find the standard error using the data given in the pic?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to construct two different CIs (for each parameter) and not simultaneously for the vector $(\beta_2, \beta_3$). As such, you can use the result 
$$
\text{var}(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} .
$$
When instead of   $\sigma^2$ you can plug-in its estimator, namely $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{10-3}\sum_{i=1}^{10} e_i^2$. And you should invert the following matrix 
$$
X'X=
\begin{bmatrix}
N     & \sum X_{2t} & \sum X_{3t} \\
\sum X_{2t} & \sum X^2_{2t} & \sum X_{2t}X_{3t} \\
\sum X_{3t} & \sum X_{3t}X_{3t} & \sum X^2_{3t}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then, $\text{var}(\hat{\beta}_i) = \hat{\sigma}^2(X'X)^{-1}_{ii}$.